# QComboBox with QPushButtons

Tags: qt, qt4, qcombobox, qtgui, qpushbutton

I would like to create a qt combo box with multiple columns containing push buttons and QLabel. If I look at the QSpinBox editor example, the editor is set only for one QSpinBox  control. Can we create a complex control such as this and handle events?

Do you have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

QCombobox internally has a abstractitemview can be accessed by:

```
QAbstractItemView * QComboBox::view () const
```

Once you have a pointer to this view, you can define your own delegate for this view. This view draw the popups.

`QAbstractItemView` can have custom delegate, which can be a push button with `QLabel` or whatever you like.

Also, you may want to use this call to make delegate showing itself when view pop up:

```
openPersistentEditor ( const QModelIndex & index )
```

Here is a demo project [QCombobox with button and spinbox](http://www.sizzls.com/2013/02/in-qt-how-to-display-button-or-spinbox-in-combobox/) exactly doing what you asking for.

Comment: A minimal example to his problem would be more usefull

Comment: 404 link error.